# SpriteBuilder image file not found

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I have added a .png image in sprit builder resource folder and I have published it.

I see the added image in sprite builder all folder in Resources under Published-IOS.

Here I have tried to access the added image in following ways.

[image]

1. `_hero.spriteFrame = [CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed:@"Down.png"];`
2. `[_hero setTexture:[CCTexture textureWithFile:@"Game/Down.png"]]`

But none of these methods are working.

it show error in log as.

```
 -[CCFileUtils fullPathForFilename:contentScale:] : cocos2d: Warning: File not found: Down.png
```

Please help me with this to resolve.Am a newbie using this sprit builder.

Comment: what folder is the image in? What's the exact name including upper/lowercase?

Comment: @ LearnCocos2D Please find my attached image in edits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `@"Down.png`" to `@"Resources/Down.png"` because you have to include the folders created in SpriteBuilder for any references to resource files managed by SpriteBuilder.

Likewise if you had some.ccb in a subfolder named "Levels" you'd have to load it with the string `@"Levels/some.ccb"`.